# Titanium module compiles but can't compile with project showing x86_64 failure

Tags: objective-c, iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-modules

I was trying to use the TiMediaPicker from the Marketplace but it had problems recognising the module. So I went to the source at https://github.com/lowb1rd/TiMediaPicker and tried to compile it.

While xCode did compile it, after I put the module in a Titanium project while trying to run the project I get the following compilation error:

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Intermediates/TestModule.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestModule.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestModule normal x86_64
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

I've created an entirely new Titanium module and started coping code to it. It seems that what's causing the problems is this line:

```
library  = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
```

But I have no idea why. Is this an x86 library? does it have alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://github.com/BouncingFish/timediapicker -- a rewrite from scratch that works with iCloud etc.

Comment: Thanks. But I see it's iOS only - the other one was for iOS and android. I would also like to understand and learn the source of the error I got. Do you know?

Comment: Ahh, ok. You tagged it as iOS so figured you just needed that.

Comment: oh. sorry about that. thought maybe it's not necessary a Titanium related issue so maybe someone who's experienced with iOS might know...

Comment: while I was finally able to compile original code from github posted above, the library you pointed out seems more impressive and more maintained. also, the other module doesn't work on android for some reason. you have any android multi-pick gallery to recommend?